# Snake Game: Drawing the body

Tags: java, android

I have been struggling with this seemingly simple problem for a few days. I want the snake to grow when it eats food by drawing a new rect where the snakes head is.

The snakes body is stored in an ArrayList, and I have been adding a rect to the body whenever it eats food. I am able to draw the snakes body, but the problem is if I try to delete the last part of the body in the for loop then it is being deleted as fast as it is drawn so the snake doesn't grow. If I delete the last part of the body outside the for loop the body grows faster than it is being deleted and it just grows without eating food.

This is where the movement is tracked

```
public void reset() {
    // reset player
    setObject(player);

    //reset apple
    setObject(apple);
}

public void setObject(GameObject obj) {
    int x = (int) (Math.random() * cols);
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * rows);
    x = x * Constants.SCALE;
    y = y * Constants.SCALE;
    if (obj instanceof Snek) {
        playerPoint = new Point(x, y);
        obj.update(playerPoint);
    }
    if (obj instanceof Snack) {
        snackPoint = new Point(x, y);
        obj.update(snackPoint);
    }
}

@Override
public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Move Left
            if (!gameOver && !movingRight && event.getX() < (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4) && event.getY() > (3 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4)) {
                movingPlayer = true;
                movingLeft = true;
                movingRight = false;
                movingDown = false;
                movingUp = false;
            }

            // Move Right
            else if (!gameOver && !movingLeft && event.getX() > (3 * Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4) && event.getY() > (3 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4)) {
                movingPlayer = true;
                movingLeft = false;
                movingRight = true;
                movingDown = false;
                movingUp = false;
            }

            // Move Down
            else if (!gameOver && !movingUp && event.getX() > (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4) && event.getX() < (3 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4) && event.getY() > (7 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 8)) {
                movingPlayer = true;
                movingLeft = false;
                movingRight = false;
                movingDown = true;
                movingUp = false;
            }

            //Move Up
            else if (!gameOver && !movingDown && event.getX() > (Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 4) && event.getX() < (3 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4) && event.getY() > (3 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4) && event.getY() < (7 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 8)) {
                movingPlayer = true;
                movingLeft = false;
                movingRight = false;
                movingDown = false;
                movingUp = true;
            }

            if (gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime > 2000) {
                reset();
                gameOver = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}

// Draw text in the center of phone
private void drawCenterText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, String text) {
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    canvas.getClipBounds(r);
    int cHeight = r.height();
    int cWidth = r.width();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
    float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
    float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
}


@Override
public void update() {
    // Always moving in one direction
    if (movingLeft && movingPlayer)
        playerPoint.set(playerPoint.x - Constants.SCALE, playerPoint.y);
    if (movingRight && movingPlayer)
        playerPoint.set(playerPoint.x + Constants.SCALE, playerPoint.y);
    if (movingDown && movingPlayer)
        playerPoint.set(playerPoint.x, playerPoint.y + Constants.SCALE);
    if (movingUp && movingPlayer)
        playerPoint.set(playerPoint.x, playerPoint.y - Constants.SCALE);

    // Game Over
    if (playerPoint.x < 0 || playerPoint.x > Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH || playerPoint.y < 0 || playerPoint.y > Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
        gameOver = true;
        movingPlayer = false;
        movingLeft = false;
        movingRight = false;
        movingDown = false;
        movingUp = false;
    }

    // Eats apple
    if (player.eat(apple)) {
        setObject(apple);
    }

    player.update(playerPoint);
    player.update();
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    player.draw(canvas);
    apple.draw(canvas);
    if (gameOver) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(100);
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        drawCenterText(canvas, paint, "Game Over");
    }
}
```

This is the snake class

```
public class Snack implements GameObject {

private Rect snack;
private int colour;

public Rect getSnack() {
    return snack;
}

public Snack(Rect snack, int colour) {
    this.snack = snack;
    this.colour = colour;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(colour);
    canvas.drawRect(snack, paint);
}

@Override
public void update() {

}

public void update(Point point) {
    snack.set(point.x - snack.width() / 2, point.y - snack.height() / 2
            , point.x + snack.width() / 2, point.y + snack.height() / 2);
}
}
```

The gap between the snakes are also too large, and I think because I set the framerate to 8 FPS. If I set it higher the snake moves too fast and the game is impossible.